# Get the number of users in my website - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, asp-classic

how can I get how many people registered to my website?
in ASP.NET

Comment: If you mean how many are registered in total, you can query your database: `SELECT COUNT(UserID) FROM user_table`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to get much better then incrementing in `Session_Start` and decrementing in `Session_End` unless you use some other means such as  a database.

When you are authenticating your requests you could update a timestamp in the database to show that the user has been active, and after a given time (say 10-15 minutes), the query thatcollects the number of current users ignores that row in the database (thus decrementing the count).